# Transform dictionary value in a single pandas dataframe column into multiple columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, series

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = { 'ID': [112,113],'empDetails':[[{'key': 'score', 'value': 2},{'key': 'Name', 'value': 'Ajay'}, {'key': 'Department', 'value': 'HR'}],[ {'key': 'salary', 'value': 7.5},{'key': 'Name', 'value': 'Balu'}]]}
dataDF = pd.DataFrame(data)

#trails
# dataDF['newColumns'] = dataDF['empDetails'].apply(lambda x: x[0].get('key'))
# dataDF = dataDF['empDetails'].apply(pd.Series)

# create dataframe
# dataDF = pd.DataFrame(dataDF['empDetails'], columns=dataDF['empDetails'].keys())

# create the dataframe
# df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(v, columns=[k]) for k, v in dataDF['empDetails'].items()], axis=1)
# print(dataDF['empDetails'].items())
display(dataDF)
```

[image]
I am trying to iterate through **empDetails** column and fetch the value of **Name**,**salary** and **Department** into **3** different column

Using pd.series I am able to split the dictionary into different columns, but not able to rename the columns as the column order may change.

What will be the effective way to do this.

Expected output
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use lambda function for extract `key`s and `value`s to new dictionaries and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
f = lambda x: {y['key']:y['value'] for y in x}
df = dataDF.join(pd.DataFrame(dataDF['empDetails'].apply(f).tolist(), index=dataDF.index))
print (df)
    ID                                         empDetails  score  Name  \
0  112  [{'key': 'score', 'value': 2}, {'key': 'Name',...    2.0  Ajay   
1  113  [{'key': 'salary', 'value': 7.5}, {'key': 'Nam...    NaN  Balu   

  Department  salary  
0         HR     NaN  
1        NaN     7.5
```

Alternative solution:

```
f = lambda x: pd.Series({y['key']:y['value'] for y in x})
df = dataDF.join(dataDF['empDetails'].apply(f))
print (df)
    ID                                         empDetails  score  Name  \
0  112  [{'key': 'score', 'value': 2}, {'key': 'Name',...    2.0  Ajay   
1  113  [{'key': 'salary', 'value': 7.5}, {'key': 'Nam...    NaN  Balu   

  Department  salary  
0         HR     NaN  
1        NaN     7.5
```

Or use list comprehension (only pandas solution):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{y['key']:y['value'] for y in x} for x in dataDF['empDetails']], 
                   index=dataDF.index)
df = dataDF.join(df1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was trying second option,but display(df) giving me 
TypeError: field Department: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'>

Comment: @USB - second option is for pure pandas only

Comment: First option too giving me the same typeerror when display(df) is used

Comment: @USB - How working alternative solution? Added to answer.

Comment: same. instead of print could you please try with display(df)

Comment: @USB - If test sample data it raise error? Or in real data?

Comment: with above sample data only

Comment: @USB - So if use `print (df)` instead `display(df)` it working? Do you run in pandas or pyspark solutions above?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python 3.5+, then you can unroll dict elements and append "ID" column in one line:

```py
df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series({**{"ID":row["ID"]}, **{ed["key"]:ed["value"] for ed in row["empDetails"]}}), axis=1)
```

**Update**: If you want all columns from original df, then use dict comprehension:

```py
df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series({**{col:row[col] for col in df.columns}, **{ed["key"]:ed["value"] for ed in row["empDetails"]}}), axis=1)
```

Full example:

```py
data = { 'ID': [112,113],'empDetails':[[{'key': 'score', 'value': 2},{'key': 'Name', 'value': 'Ajay'}, {'key': 'Department', 'value': 'HR'}],[ {'key': 'salary', 'value': 7.5},{'key': 'Name', 'value': 'Balu'}]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series({**{col:row[col] for col in df.columns}, **{ed["key"]:ed["value"] for ed in row["empDetails"]}}), axis=1)

[Out]:
  Department   ID  Name  salary  score
0         HR  112  Ajay     NaN    2.0
1        NaN  113  Balu     7.5    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to pull empDetails also along with ID, so instead of giving separate cols {"ID":row["ID"]} can we give some syntax which can pull all the existing cols from df? Have mentioned expected output.

Comment: I've updated the answer for retaining all columns from original df.

Comment: If I am replacing 3rd line in full example block and display the df it is giving me field Department: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'>

Comment: I updated the full example with to retain original columns. I'm not getting any error. Possibly, there is some data issue at your end. Can you reproduce the problem [colab](https://colab.research.google.com) and share the link with public access?

Comment: sure. Here is the link : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OctkV-53DPYTYRHLjoST7fRY9NQzaiel?usp=sharing

Comment: @USB - Solution working well in your colab for me, for you not?

Comment: I am trying this solution through Azure databricks notebook and there it is not working as expected

Comment: @USB, what issue are you getting? I could run the colab code you have shared with no issue.

Comment: @USB, I'll suggest you create another question with details of the issue you are getting and if possible, provide the dataset you are using via gdrive share. Please provide all source code as text to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sure. I am using the same snippet in colab. There it is working fine for me, but not through databricks notebook. I am wondering what the issue is. I have pasted error line and error in the same collab code